# how to activate bold tags when click and deactivate when click again in HTML/javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to know if there's a way in HTML/javascript/jquery to create the bold button like in MS.WORD.

When we click the bold button, any text we type in the textbox/textarea will be bold but when we click the button again, any text we type will be normal again but the bolded text will still be bold

any suggestion will be highly appreciated
thanks

Comment: There are a number of ways to accomplish what you are asking. What have you tried and what is your application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a built in way to do this, since presentation and data are separated through CSS and HTML. There are a number of html5 wysiwyg editors that provide this ability

1. [wysihtml5](http://xing.github.io/wysihtml5/)
2. [bootstrap-wysiwyg](http://mindmup.github.io/bootstrap-wysiwyg/)
3. [raptor editor](https://www.raptor-editor.com/)

[and many more](https://www.google.com/search?q=rich+text+editor+html5)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of different plugins to accomplish what you are asking. For example the [TinyMCE jQuery plugin](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/3_x/jquery_version.php).

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want tinymce style editor then try this one please
http://jsfiddle.net/Ys5ZU/2/

I added jquery, but you could do it without it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#change").click(function(){
        $("#text").toggleClass("big");
        $("#text").hasClass("big")?$("#change").val("bold"):$("#change").val("normal")
    });
});
```